# Are python literals saved inside function bodies?

Tags: python, scopes

I have a function which needs to execute inside a fairly tight loop so it's performance sensitive.  Its a filtering function intended to save more expensive work.  Most of the function is just a check against a static list.

So (stripping out some irrelevant detail) I could do two different things here:

```
 def my_filter(arg):
    SAFE_VALS = {
        'a',
        'b',
        'f',
        'i',
        'm'
    }
   # the real list is much larger, but 
   # it is a static set like the above...

    return arg in SAFE_VALS
```

or

```
 # make this a module level constant
 SAFE_VALS = {
        'a',
        'b',
        'f',
        'i',
        'm'
    }

 def my_filter(arg):
    return arg in SAFE_VALS
```

I know that Python will have to look one scope level higher to find the module level version -- but what I don't know is whether the compiled version of `my_filter` effectively recreates this set every time the function is run or if the literal is "baked in" to the function def.  If every invocation allocates a new set, it feels like I'd be better off with the module level version -- if not, I don't gain anything by hoisting the literal out of the function scope.

Right now the profiling data is noisy enough that I don't see a clear difference. But if that set includes a much larger number of longish strings will I? Or is there just now significant difference between these forms?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As a matter of language semantics, `{'a', 'b', 'f', 'i', 'm'}` means "make a *new* set with these contents". The language semantics allow reusing an existing object for immutable types, but sets are mutable.

As an implementation detail, CPython currently optimizes expressions of the form `x in {stuff}`, where the right-hand side is a set expression containing only constants. In that case, Python will precompute a frozenset and save it in the code object's `co_consts`. Saving the set to a variable prevents the optimization.

To guarantee the set is not recomputed, independent of implementation details, you should precompute the set yourself and save `SAFE_VALS` as a global variable.

Comment: Ah -- thanks for mentioning `co_consts` -- I should have realized I could see it there.